# fastCGI environment variables - where can I get a (standard/official) list from?

Tags: c++, c, linux, apache, fastcgi

I am developing a C/C++ fastCGI app and I need to know the set of environment variables, that are available to a fastCGI.

I am looking for a standard (or official) list, but suprisingly, this does not exist in the fastCGI specification itself. Does anyone know where I can obtain an 'official' list from?

I am developing/testing with Apache 2.2. + mod_fcgid on Ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

Are FastCGI environment variables different from CGI? If not, then [RFC 3875](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) contains the CGI specification.

Answer (score 1):

The [FastCGI standard](https://fastcgi-archives.github.io/FastCGI_Specification.html) states that

> The Responder application receives CGI/1.1 environment variables from the Web server over FCGI_PARAMS.

That implies, to me at least, that it supplies all the CGI environment variables as well as its own. They don't actually arrive as separate environment variables, but via a stream. Again quoting the standard:

> FCGI_PARAMS
>
> is a stream record type used in sending name-value pairs from the Web
> server to the application. The name-value pairs are sent down the
> stream one after the other, in no specified order.

If you use a FastCGI library it will supply an easy way of getting these variables. For example, the C++ library [fcgi2](https://github.com/FastCGI-Archives/fcgi2) provides the function `FCGX_GetParam` to get a value for a variable. Here's a code snippet illustrating this:

```
    const char* q = FCGX_GetParam("QUERY_STRING",aRequest.envp);
```

I have verified the behaviour of FastCGI and the fcgi2 library in practice on Windows IIS by writing a FastCGI program and examining its behaviour.